# continuity of complex function at a point

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

I need to show that $$\lim_{z \to -i} \frac{z^2+2iz-1}{2z^2+iz+1}=0$$
I've made the function equal $z+1/2z-1$ but I'm not sure where to go from there?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{z^2+2iz-1}{2z^2+iz+1}=\frac{(z+i)^2}{(z+i)(z-i/2)}=\frac{z+i}{z-i/2}$$

Plugging $z=-i$

we get $$\frac{-i+i}{-i-i/2}=0$$